# Memory profile shows texture size different than actual size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, memory-profiling

I am downloading texture at runtime. The actual texture size is 3 MB, 2.5 MB, 1 MB but in Memory profiler it shows 18 MB. So how can i fix it?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNe00.png)

I try to reduce texture size after downloading. But it does not works

Answer (score 0):

Size 3 MB, 2.5 MB, 1 MB is the **size of file** on disk. This is a compressed texture size.

18 Mb is the size of the **unpacked texture** in memory, i.e. width * height * pixel size.

To reduce the size of the texture in memory and data file size, you can select a compression format suitable for [the task and the target platform](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterOverride.html).

The texture pixel format\compression can be changed in Inspector in Texture import settings panel for each texture.